# Evaluating a definite integral by definition: $A(x) = \int_{-1}^x (t^2 + 1)\space dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, definition

I have an area function $A(x)$ defined as

$$A(x) = \int_{-1}^{x} (t^2 + 1)\space dt$$

... and I would like to use the definition of definite integral to evaluate it.

I started this way
$$A(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n { (t^2 + 1) {x - (-1) \over n}}\tag 1$$

I thought that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n {x +1 \over n }\tag 2$$ turns into $x + 1$, so that

$$A(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \space\sum_{k=1}^n { t^2}{x + 1 \over n}  + x + 1\tag 3$$
and saying that $t = k{x + 1 \over n}$ it would become
 $$A(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \space\sum_{k=1}^n { k^2 (x+1)^3 \over n^3} + x + 1\tag4$$

I'm not sure if I didn't make any mistake until here, and even if I didn't, I don't know what to do now. Maybe I could use 
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{n} k^2 = {n(n + 1)(2n + 1) \over 6}\tag 5$$
but in order to do that, I would have to first get rid of $n^2$ in denominator.

Could you please give me a friendly kick in the head to make it correct? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I later replaced $t$ with an expression containing $k$.

Comment: you have to denote it by $t_k$ in the begining and $t_k=-1+k\frac{x+1}{n}$ because your integral starts from $-1$

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add ${ x + 1 \over n}$, if that's the only thing.

Comment: No, surely it isn't, as I see now. I'll ask under your answer.

Comment: See the definition in the first line of my answer.  This is the Riemann integral.  Why is it defined like this?  It is an approximation to the area under a curve using successively smaller rectangles under the curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that

$$\int_a^b dt \, f(t) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=0}^n f \left [ a + (b-a) \frac{k}{n} \right ] $$

Here, $a=-1$ and $b=x$, so that the sum we are interested in is

$$ \begin{align} \int_{-1}^x dt \, (1+t^2) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x+1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^n \left [ 1+ \left ( -1 + \frac{x+1}{n} k \right )^2 \right ]  \\ &= x+1 + \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x+1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^n \left [1 - 2 \frac{x+1}{n} k + \left ( \frac{x+1}{n} \right )^2 k^2 \right ]\\ &= 2 (x+1) + \lim_{n \to \infty} \left [\frac{-2 (x+1)^2}{n^2} \sum_{k=0}^n k + \frac{(x+1)^3}{n^3} \sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \right ]\\ &= 2 (x+1) + \lim_{n \to \infty} \left [\frac{-2 (x+1)^2}{n^2} \frac{n (n+1)}{2} + \frac{(x+1)^3}{n^3} \frac{n (n+1) (2 n+1)}{6} \right] \\ &= 2 (x+1) - (x+1)^2 + \frac13 (x+1)^3 \\ &= \frac13 (x+1) (x^2-x+4)\end{align}$$

You can verify that this is what you get by integrating using the Fundamental theorem.

Answer (score 1):

There is my calculation to make compare it with what you did, we will  use the definition, let $f(t)=t^2+1$ and $x_k=-1+k\frac{x-(-1)}{n}$:
$$\begin{align}A(x)&= \int_{-1}^x (t^2+1)\\ \\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x-(-1)}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_k)\\ \\ 
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x+1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\left(k\frac{x+1}{n}-1\right)^2+1\right)\\ \\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x+1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(k^2\left(\frac{x+1}{n}\right)^2-2k\frac{x+1}{n}+2\right)\\ \\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x+1}{n} \left(\left(\frac{x+1}{n}\right)^2\sum_{k=1}^nk^2-\frac{x+1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n2k+\sum_{k=1}^n2\right)\\ \\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x+1}{n} \left(\left(\frac{x+1}{n}\right)^2{n(n + 1)(2n + 1) \over 6}-\frac{x+1}{n}n(n+1)+2n\right)\\ \\
&=(x+1)\left(\frac{(x+1)^2}{3}-(x+1)+2\right)\\ \\
&=\frac{(x+1)(x^2-x+4)}{3}\end{align}$$

Comment: Ok, now I understand the process and what I was missing. But as you wrote under the question, and as you both answered: $x_k = -1 + k {x+1 \over n}$ - why? Ok, I was taught that (in my words) $x_k = k {b - a \over n}$ where $b - a$ is the length of interval, $n$ is the number of approximation rectangles and $k$ is the "step" $0 < k < n$. Why $-1$?

Comment: check the definition in your book always we have :$x_k=a+k\frac{b-a}{n}$ and in this question $a=-1$

Comment: Oh, you're right, now I understand it, thank you! I don't know, is it polite accept another answer once I've already accepted?

Comment: @user35443: you may do what you want.  However, keep in mind that the two answers are basically identical, and I had already explained what Elaqqad had explained in my answer.